# What is an easy way to get today's 0am in Flutter?

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart

I would like to know nice ways to get today's 0am as a `DateTime` variable. Could you advise me?

Examples

```
// Suppose today is April 18, 2020
DateTime _dateTime = {DO_SOMETHING};
print(_dateTime); // Expected output: 2020-04-18 00:00:00

// Suppose today is October 22, 2019
DateTime _dateTime = {DO_SOMETHING};
print(_dateTime); // Expected output: 2019-10-22 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no built-in methods available to get only date. You can construct it in the following way:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();
DateTime date = DateTime(dateTime.year, dateTime.month, dateTime.day);
print(date); // Prints 2020-04-18 00:00:00.000
```

You can also use [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) or [jiffy](https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy) packages to convert the dates in your desired formats.